# GYP issue installing yo hyperledger

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, hyperledger, gyp

I can't install hyperledger on windows 10 using VSCode because I keep getting a error when I try to install the generator with Yo.

This is the error:

```
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-hyperledger-composer\node_modules\pkcs11js>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp
(node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
The system cannot find the path specified.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\program files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-hyperledger-composer\node_modules\pkcs11js
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.17 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.17 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Thanks for the help!